# Sql command: How to get rows from specified value?

Tags: sql-server

Please advise SQL command.

I have a table with 3 columns: `Data, Quantity, Price`

But number of rows about thousand.

I have exact number of rows (for example only 5), which I want to pickup from this table (see below).

So I want to collect data after "06.02.2013" (if this date not in table, possible to take next nearest date after this date, it will be 11.02.2013), 
and collect 5 rows after this date (result see below)

**table_Prices**:

```
 Date      Qty   Price
-----------------------
01.02.2013  24  1025
06.02.2013  26  1150
11.02.2013  47  2014
16.02.2013  5   1025
21.02.2013  7   1023
26.02.2013  8   1025
03.03.2013  95  1203
08.03.2013  63  1203
13.03.2013  25  2012
18.03.2013  48  1032
23.03.2013  105 1253
28.03.2013  48  1452
```

Desired result:

```
06.02.2013  26  1150
11.02.2013  47  2014
16.02.2013  5   1025
21.02.2013  7   1023
26.02.2013  8   1025
```

Comment: Read about and understand how TOP and ORDER BY can accomplish this for you.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: So you mean select top(5) where date > x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 5 *
from table_Prices
where Date > cast('06-02-2013' as datetime)
order by Date asc
```

Comment: This would be better if the date string was ANSI standard. '20130602' or YYYYMMDD.

Comment: I am novice  in SQL and I have spend about two hours to combine the command, but actually query was  much more easy than I thought  . Thank you very much.